# Evaluate $\int_{|z|=r}^{}\frac{\log\ z}{z^2+1}dz$ where $r>0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I tried to evaluate $$\int_{|z|=r}^{}\frac{\log\ z}{z^2+1}dz$$ when $r>0$. Clearly $\log z$ is not continuous at $z=-r$. So is this integral meaningful then? Since the function is continuous and bounded on  the given path except only at this point, I am thinking it should be possible to actually evaluate this. Hope someone could help me out with this confusion and help to evaluate this integral. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A branch of the logarithm is defined in a region, $G\subseteq\dot{\mathbb{C}}$, if and only if for every cycle, $\Gamma$, contained in $G$, $n(\Gamma, 0) = 0$, where $n(\Gamma,0)$ is the winding number, which represents the number of times the curve goes around $0$.

In your particular case, whichever region containing the curve you're integrating over doesn't satisfy this condition, so you can't define a branch of the logarithm.

Basically, you can't find any branch of the logarithm which is well defined in a region containing your curve.

Note: I've seen in some places the notation $\operatorname{Log}$ used to refer to the principal branch. If your adhering to this convention, then everything is ok. If you aren't then it is possible to define a branch of the logarithm in the negative real axis, as long as the condition I mentioned is satisfied.

Comment: Yes I am referring to the principal branch and know that this is integrable but I don't how that's possible

Comment: Well, as I said in my answer, this is not defined in your whole domain. To integrate the principal branch you should remove the point $-r$ from the integration. What you can do is calculate the principal value:
$$
PV-\int_{|z|=r} \frac{\operatorname{Log}z}{z^2+1}dz = \lim_{\epsilon\to \pi^-}\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\frac{\operatorname{Log}(re^{it})}{r^2e^{2it}+1}(ire^{it})dt
$$

Comment: I see. Never seen this in any text I have read thanks alot

Comment: This can be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value