# does $\int_\gamma ln(z) dz$ depend on the branch cut I choose?

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to know why do I get two different results when I calculate $\int_\gamma ln(z) dz$ ,with $\gamma$ the unit cercle, when using two different branch cuts $[0,+\infty[$ and $]-\infty,0]$ ?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I explained in my answer here: [Evaluate $\int_{|z|=r}^{}\frac{\log\ z}{z^2+1}dz$ where $r>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008363/int-z-r-frac-text-log-zz21dz-r0/1010105#1010105)

You can't define a branch of the logarithm in any cycle which goes around de origin, so your integral isn't well defined. As I also pointed out in that answer, at most, you could try to calculate the principal value.